# How to push a commit with a tag to a remote branch in git?

Tags: git, push

I would like to push a commit with a particular tag (T) to a branch (B).

I am using the following command:

```
git push origin refs/tags/T:refs/heads/B
```

The command fails with

> ! [remote rejected] T -> B (failed to write)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'

NOTE: There is not branch B in the remote origin.

NOTE2: When I use `git push origin T:B`, it creates a tag B on the remote.

NOTE3: When I use `git push origin 45feef5:B, it works. However I would like to use tag name instead of the commit hash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible. [Git docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) says:

> By default, the `git push` command doesn’t transfer tags to remote servers. You will have to explicitly push tags to a shared server after you have created them.